# How to Count number of pages of an online pdf in python?

Tags: python, pypdf

I am analyzing NLP conferences. I need to extract number of pages from pdfs which are hosted online, using python. 
For example :
             The source of the pdf is "https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/E91-1002.pdf"
             The output should be 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would [scrape](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/) it and then extract the information with [PyPdf2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/).

Answer (score 3):

As Darjusch suggested, use PyPDF2.

`PdfFileReader` doesn't take raw bytes, so you need to create a `file like` object, initialised with bytes of the pdf file.

```py
import PyPDF2, io, requests

response = requests.get("https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/E91-1002.pdf")
pdf_file = io.BytesIO(response.content) # response being a requests Response object
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
num_pages = pdf_reader.numPages
```

or as one line:

```py
num_pages = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(response.content)).numPages
```

`num_pages` is 6, as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But can you give the full code ? My pdf is residing online. Consider the pdf ='https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/E91-1002.pdf'. I know the url of the pdf. Now what should be the full code to extract number of pages ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. It downloads that specific pdf file. It doesn't do any scraping.